# Lagrange multipliers and confidence interval

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, inference

> Suppose $X_1,...X_n$ is a random sample  from $X$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$,
>   with $\sigma^2$ unknow. If
>   $$[\overline{X}+z_{a_2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}};\overline{X}-z_{a_1}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}]$$
>   is a confidence interval for $\mu$ where $a_1+a_2=a$ and $z_w$ is such
>   that $P(X\leq z_w)=w$ where $Z$~$N(0,1)$. Show that the length of the
>   invertal is shortest when $a_1=a_2=\frac{a}{2}$

I know that the lenght of interval $L$ is $$\overline{X}-z_{a_1}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}-(\overline{X}+z_{a_2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})=-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}(z_{a_1}+z_{a_2})$$

First I have that 
$$P(\overline{X}+z_{a_2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\mu\leq\overline{X}-z_{a_1}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})=1-\alpha$$
developing this I have that $$\phi(z_{a_1})+\phi(z_{a_2})=\alpha$$

Suppose that $f(z_{a_1},z_{a_2})=z_{a_1}+z_{a_2}$

and that the condition I have is $g(z_{a_1},z_{a_2})=\phi(z_{a_1})+\phi(z_{a_2})=\alpha$

Now I have that 
$$(1)f_{z_{a_1}}=\lambda g_{z_{a_1}} \Leftrightarrow 1=\lambda\frac{dg}{dz_{a_1}}\phi(z_{a_1})$$
$$(2)f_{z_{a_2}}=\lambda g_{z_{a_2}} \Leftrightarrow 1=\lambda\frac{dg}{dz_{a_2}}\phi(z_{a_2})$$
$$(3)g(z_{a_1},z_{a_2})=\phi(z_{a_1})+\phi(z_{a_2})=\alpha$$

Making $(1)-(2)$
$$(4)\lambda[\frac{dg}{dz_{a_1}}\phi(z_{a_1})-\frac{dg}{dz_{a_2}}\phi(z_{a_2})]=0$$

$(4)$ is valid if $\lambda=1$ and $\frac{dg}{dz_{a_1}}\phi(z_{a_1})=\frac{dg}{dz_{a_2}}\phi(z_{a_2})$,  from this I have that

$$\phi(z_{a_1})+\phi(z_{a_2})=\phi(z_{a_1})+\phi(z_{a_1})=a_1+a_1=2a_1=\alpha\Rightarrow a_1=\frac{\alpha}{2}$$ and similary $a_2=\frac{\alpha}{2}$

Comment: I don't understand your question here. Based on CLT, $\bar{X}$ follows a normal distribution asymptotically, which is a symmetric distribution. Then give the confidence level, you will be easily figure out the IC, and $q_1$ will be equal to $q_2$, which leads to lowest range.

Comment: @AaronZeng No reference to CLT or asymptotics is needed here. The $X_i$ are _given_ to be independent _normal_ random variables and so $\bar{X}$ is known to be $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ for all positive integers $n$ right there in Chapter 6, long before one gets to Chapter 8 and the CLT and asymptotics.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't paying attention on the iid normal random variables. Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you can give a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate somewhat over the comment of @AaronZeng:

Let $f$ be a unimodal density function of a continuous r.v. (the latter for simplicity). If the interval $[a,b]$ satisfies

1. $\int_a^bf(x)dx=1-\alpha$
2. $f(a)=f(b)>0$
3. $a\leqslant x^* \leqslant b$, where $x^*$ is the mode of $f(x)$,

then $[a,b]$ is the shortest interval satisfying 1.

Proof: 
For some fixed $c$, Leibniz' Theorem gives that
$$
\frac{d}{da}\int_a^{a+c}f(x)dx=f(a+c)-f(a)
$$
Setting this derivative to zero gives the first order condition $f(a+c)=f(a)$. This is a maximum, because unimodality and continuity imply that $a\leqslant x^*\leqslant a+c$ and continuity implies that for any $a'>(<)a$, $\int_a^{a'}f(x)dx>(<)\int_{a+c}^{a'+c}f(x)dx$, such that
$$
\int_a^{a+c}f(x)dx>\int_{a'}^{a'+c}f(x)dx\qquad\text{for any }a'
$$
Now, choose $a^*$ and $c^*$ such that $\int_{a^*}^{a^*+c^*}f(x)dx=1-\alpha$ and $f(a^*+c^*)=f(a^*)$. By the previous results, that maximizes the area under the integral, to the desired area $1-\alpha$. Hence $\int_{a^*+\epsilon}^{a^*+c^*+\epsilon}f(x)dx<1-\alpha$, so that we would need to widen the interval to some $[a^*+\epsilon,a^*+c^*+\epsilon+\delta]$ to maintain a coverage probability of $1-\alpha$.

Here is a figure trying to illustrate: First, we have a 90% equitailed confidence interval between the 5%-quantile $-z_{\alpha/2}$ and 95%-quantile $z_{\alpha/2}$. Second, the interval between the 9%- and 99%-quantile is also a 90%-c.i., but we can see that it is longer: we must move the right endpoint by more to the right than the distance between the two left endpoints to ensure the same area under the density, as the density *increases* to the right of $-z_{\alpha/2}$, but *decreases* to the right of $z_{\alpha/2}$.

[image]

Comment: You know how to find the constants that minimize the confidence interval length using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Never looked at it from that angle yet, no.

Answer (score 3):

I avoid discussing "z-scores" and "$p$-values" because I have very little understanding of what these things, so dear to the statistical heart, 
actually mean.

You have $n$ independent identically distributed normal random variables $X_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$ with unknown mean $\mu$ but known variance $\sigma^2$. Their *average*
$$\bar{X} = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
is also a normal random variable with $\mu$ but smaller variance $\sigma^2/n$.

---

Now, for a $N(\mu,\tau^2)$ random variable $Y$,
$$P\{\mu-1.96 \tau \leq Y \leq \mu+1.96\tau\} = 0.95\tag{1}$$
If we knew the value of $\mu$, we could construct the interval
$\mathcal I = [\mu-1.96 \tau, \leq \mu+1.96\tau]$ and be assured that when we
do the experiment over and over, on $95\%$ of such trials, the value
of $Y$ will lie in $\mathcal I$. We don't know $\mu$, however. But we
have observed that $Y$ has taken on value $y$ in the trial just concluded. Now, if $y \in \mathcal I$, then it must be that 
$\mu \in [y-1.96 \tau, y + 1.96 \tau]$. We don't know 
whether or not the specific $y$ that we observed lies in $\mathcal I$,
but we might feel some confidence, perhaps 95% confidence, that
$y$ is one of the "good guys" that belongs to belongs to $\mathcal I$,
and so we are 95% confident that $\mu \in [y-1.96 \tau, y + 1.96 \tau]$.

---

The midpoint of the interval $\mathcal I$ defined by $(1)$ is $\mu$.
Now, there are uncountably many real numbers $a$ such that
$$P\{a \leq Y \leq b(a)\} = 0.95\tag{2}$$ (Here $b(a)$ is a number, obviously
dependent on $a$ such that the equality holds in $(2)$.  The *function*
$b(a)$ has value approximately $\mu+1.65\tau$ when $a = -\infty$. It increases slowly and has value $\mu+1.96\tau$ when $a=\mu-1.96\tau$. It then increases very rapidly and approaches $\infty$ as $a$ gets
close to $\mu-1.65\tau$. There are
no solutions to $(2)$ if $a > \mu-1.65\tau$.  So, when does the
*length* $b(a)-a$ of the interval have a minimum? Symmetry 
suggests that the minimum occurs
when $a$ and $b(a)$ are equally far from the mean $\mu$, and
we can do a formal proof via calculus as in Christoph Hanck's answer.

---

I have not thought about applying Lagrange multipliers to the
problem.